# C++11: Replace all non-owning raw pointers with std::shared_ptr()?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, smart-pointers

With the advent of `std::unique_ptr`, the blemished `std::auto_ptr` can finally be put to rest.  So for the last several days, I have been changing my code to use smart pointers and to eliminate all `delete` from my code.

Although valgrind says my code is memory-clean, the semantic richness of smart pointers will make for cleaner and easier-to-understand code.

In most of the code, the translation is simple: use `std::unique_ptr` for in place of the raw pointers held by the owning objects, throw out `delete`, and carefully sprinkle `get()`, `reset()` and `move()` calls, as needed, to interface well with the rest of the code.

I am at the point where I am translating **non-owning raw pointers** to smart pointers now.

Since I was careful with the lifetimes of my objects (I ensure my modules only depend in one direction), valgrind tells me that I don't have any uninitialized reads, dangling pointers, or leaks.  So, technically, I could just leave those **non-owning raw pointers** alone now.

However, one option is to change those **non-owning raw pointers** to `std::shared_ptr` because I know they are acyclic.  Or, would it be better to leave them as raw pointers?

*I need some advice from veteran users of smart pointers as to what rules of thumb you use to decide whether to keep **non-owning raw pointers** as-is, or to translate them into `std::shared_ptr`,* keeping in mind that I constantly unit-test and valgrind my code.

EDIT:  I might be misunderstanding the use of `std::shared_ptr` - can they be used in conjunction with `std::unique_ptr`, or is it the case that if I use `std::shared_ptr`, all handles should also be `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Shared pointers are owning

Comment: So all shared pointers essentially "equally own" the object, right?  So I should keep it as one unique ptr + many raw pointers or just many shared pointers, depending on my semantic intent?  Would that be right?

Comment: @kfmfe04: Use a `shared_ptr` when you require multiple things own a resource (and those owning things may go in and out of scope at "random"), use a `unique_ptr` when a single thing owns the resource, and use a raw pointer when you just need to refer to it, and not own it (and expect this referral to not last longer than the resource exists).

Comment: @GMan: +1 good answer to all my questions - tyvm

Comment: You could use one shared ptr and many weak ptrs.

Comment: Hey, what happened here? Did a mod convert all answers to comments?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - I thought it odd that no one posted in the Answer area - these are some good, clarifying comments.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Heh, no, I just tend to leave information in comments let other people answer. I suppose I could make the move.

Comment: @kfmfe04: what you need here is a `dumb_ptr`! `template <typename T> using dumb_ptr = T*;` (just to make this clear, I'm joking.)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: rofl - I felt like a dumb_ptr when a zoo full of smart_ptr's were rolled out for C++ over the years!

Comment: @R.Martinho: `nonowning_ptr` :P

Comment: There is a proposal for a non-owning "dumb" smart pointer, called "observer_ptr" that has no real purpose but to clarify the non-owning role of the pointer: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Personally, this is how I (more or less) do it:

- **unique_ptrs** are for sole ownership
- **raw pointers** mean whoever gave me the raw pointer guarantees the lifetime of that object to match or exceed my lifetime.
- **shared_ptrs** are for shared ownership
- **weak_ptrs** are for when a system wants to check if the object still exists before using it. This is rare in my code since I find it cleaner to have a system guarantee the lifetime of anything it passes it's subsystems (in which case I use a raw pointer)

By far I use more unique_ptrs than shared_ptrs, and more raw pointers than weak pointers.

Comment: +1  Don't make easy things hard.  Don't make simple things complicated.

Comment: +1 your observations are consistent with my limited experience in this area - nice to get an affirmation and a clear statement of usage - ty

Comment: There seem to be very few cases, when you would use a *raw pointer* over a *reference*. Or do you seriously check whether the pointer is a `nullptr` before using it?

Comment: @LCIDFire No, I virtually never pass a raw pointer which optionally can be null; That's no the reason to pass by raw pointer. I pass by reference when the object is only used in the scope of the method. I pass by pointer when the method stores off the pointer (generally as a class member) beyond the scope of it's call. Obviously, you could just take the address of a reference passed to you, but I believe doing what I said above is clearer.

Comment: Plus you can always check if a `shared_ptr` is valid by coercing it to a bool.

Answer (score 11):

Use a `shared_ptr` when you require multiple things own a resource (and those owning things may go in and out of scope at "random"), use a `unique_ptr` when a single thing owns the resource, and use a raw pointer when you just need to refer to it and not own it (and expect this referral to not last longer than the resource exists).

There is a fourth type, a sort of raw-pointer-for-`shared_ptr`'s, called `weak_ptr`. You use that to refer to a `shared_ptr` without actually owning it; you can then check if the object is still there and use it.

Answer (score 8):

The only non-owning smart-pointer in the standard library is `std::weak_ptr`. However, to use it, the actual owning object needs to hold the pointee in a `std::shared_ptr`.

I assume you used `std::unique_ptr` on those before. If you convert them to `shared_ptr` now, you'll have the benefit that your non-owning pointers can know that the owning pointer lost is reference while raw pointers can be left dangling without any chance for the non-owning component to detect this. However, `shared_ptr` will incur a (very?) small performance and memory overhead over `unique_ptr`.

Personally, I recommend using one `shared_ptr` and many `weak_ptr`s instead of one `unique_ptr` and many raw-pointers in the general case and use `unique_ptr` if you really have a performance problem!

Comment: +1 to the use of `weak_ptr` for holding pointer references, even if there is only one owner. The nice thing about `weak_ptr` is that it actually *checks* to see if the object is gone. It gives you the power to put in some verification to see if an object was deleted. A naked pointer can't do that.