# Smart pointers + cycles + "->"

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

Sometimes I'm really sure that I want to have circular dependence of pointers, and every object on cycle should be able to use his pointer (so it can't be weak_ptr).

My question is: Does this mean that I have bad design?

What if I want to implement graph? Can I use smart pointers? In graphs there are cycles, but with weak_ptr I can't use "->". What can I do?

I read some articles, reference and topics on StackOverflow, but it looks like I still don't get smart pointers. Really, why doesn't exists some variant of weak_ptr with "->"?

Comment: General graphs implementations avoid the issue by using either a matrix or list format to represent relationships, rather than actual pointers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)#Representations

Comment: @StoryTeller matrix takes a lot of space, much more than needed and in general case it is not good idea. Having a list is what the OP is talking about - having pointers to adjacent nodes.

Comment: @Andrey, no that is not what the OP is talking about. He was talking about having edges represented by actual pointers. If he had an adjacency or incidence list in mind, he would not feel he can't use a weak pointer, since those are just condensed forms of the matrix.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't get it, if you define `struct Node { whatever data; vector<Node*> nodes; }` basically that what I understand by adjacency list. So in this case you need some sort of reference to nodes.

Comment: @Andrey, That is the naive implementation which is prone to the problem the OP is asking about. Having `struct Node { whatever data; vector<Node_ID> nodes; }` and using a table to retrieve actual nodes is what I was talking about.

Comment: @StoryTeller I meant that it looks like OP is only aware of the native one, so you should have showed it as an answer.

Comment: Just an aside but do you actually want to implement your own graph library? If so, I would just just use boost graph. I say this because I went down this road myself (I used shared_ptr's with raw pointers to  break cycles) and while I learned a lot about c++, smart pointers, graph theory, etc, I ultimately learned how hard it is to write a good graph theory library and just went with boost graph.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Approach this from the conceptual side, not the implementation one. Smart pointers represent *ownership.* And existence of smart pointers does not invalidate the role of raw pointers as non-owning observers.

Does each object have a single, clearly defined owner (e.g. a graph owns all of its vertices and edges)? If so, use `std::unique_ptr` to hold the vertices and edges in the graph, and use raw pointers inside vertices and edges to refer to each other.

Is shared ownership applicable (e.g. a vertex only exists as long as at least one edge is connected to it)? If so, use `std::shared_ptr` to represent that ownership, again with raw pointers for non-owning observers. If you need mutual ownership (i.e. ownership cycles) where "a vertex only exists as long as an edge refers to it, and an edge only exists as long as a vertex refers to it," then 1. double-check that such design is correct and maintainable, and 2. if so, use a `std::weak_ptr` somewhere in the cycle to break the ownership loop. You can always `lock()` a `weak_ptr` to obtain a `shared_ptr`.

For your particular graph scenario, I believe "everything's owned by the graph" would be the most logical ownership scheme; but that depends on the idiosyncracies of your task.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!
So, raw pointers are still consistent with rules of good programming, as representation of some connection, but not ownership?

Comment: But wait: weak pointer is something defined as non-owning ("weak") reference. So I still don't know: why I can't use it to access an object, without conversion to shared_ptr?
Is having a lot of weak_ptrs and for every use, converting them to shared_ptr, a good practice? It looks like a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: @KrzysztofStanisławek Yes, exactly. Herb sutter has [:several:](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) [:articles:](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) on this. There's also a [question here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8338570/1782465).

Comment: @KrzysztofStanisławek A `weak_ptr` can't be directly dereferences precisely because it's non-owning; it can become "dangling" if all `shared_ptr`s to its object are destroyed. Use a `weak_ptr` if you can outlive the thing it points to, or a raw pointer if you cannot.

Comment: @Angew I can understand your point about having the graph contain a `std::unique_ptr`, but in practice, it shouldn't be necessary, and it adds a lot of extra overhead and complexity.  A graph is a somewhat special case where the object (the graph) owing the dynamically allocated pointer (the nodes in the graph) may not even have a pointer to them.  But it does know how to get to them, and in the destructor, it will walk the graph to delete whatever.  (Although graphs are a case where a garbage collector does a lot better job.)

Comment: I like this answer, but I want to note that `weak_ptr` can only break cycles statically, i.e. cycles known at compile-time.

Comment: @KrzysztofStanislawek Following a non-owning reference to an unknown lifetime object has to be a two step process.  First, you have to check that the object still exists, then you have to use the object.  You could have a `throw`ing `operator->` like interface, but `weak_ptr` instead makes you generate the `shared_ptr`, ensure it is valid, use it, then discard the `shared_ptr`.  Writing a `throw` based interface around this is not hard...

Comment: @JamesKanze complexity maybe, but overhead? I always though that unique pointers had zero overhead.

Comment: @AlessandroStamatto How could they have zero overhead?  But in this case, I was talking about the overhead of having to keep `unique_ptr` somewhere, since they can't be used in the graph itself.  A graph class might normally contain just a pointer to a root, even if it is the owner of all of the nodes.  If it wants to count on `unique_ptr` for the deletes, then it needs to keep pointers to all of the nodes.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'd say most generic graphs don't have a root.

Comment: @Angew It depends on your definition of root.  They all have some sort of entry point, even if it isn't special once you're in the graph.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `weak_ptr` somewhere in the cycle; you just need to promote the `weak_ptr`s to `shared_ptr`s before you can dereference them. You can do this by calling `weak_ptr::lock()` or simply by passing a `weak_ptr` to `shared_ptr`'s constructor (but beware; this will throw a `bad_weak_ptr` exception if the object the `weak_ptr` points to has been destroyed.

If you really can't do this (for example, if all objects involved in the cycle are of the same type, which is probably the case in your graph example), another option is to put a `release` function somewhere in the chain that causes the object in question to set all its `shared_ptr`s to null.

Comment: Sounds like a great recipe for making the code for walking the graph unreadable.  _All_ of the pointers in the graph would have to be weak pointers, and they are probably all of the pointers which exist for most of the nodes.

Comment: @JamesKanze Right; the idea in the first paragraph is a good solution when the cycle is composed of different kinds of objects, but it becomes more difficult when they're all the same (that's what I try to address with the second paragraph). Without seeing his actual code, it's hard to make a concrete suggestion for what OP should do. And it sounded like he was interested in general solutions, rather than just a solution for a graph.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that I have bad design?

Yes, but it is a starting point.

Let's consider some of the smart pointers availabe to use.

`unique_ptr` - a single owner exists that is responsible for disposing of the object.

`shared_ptr` - many (or potentially many) owners exist and the last one must dispose of the object

`weak_ptr` - many owners may exist but this is not one of them, the weak pointer may out live the object pointed to, if the object pointed to is disposed of the weak pointer will be null (that is the lock method will return a null shared_ptr)

`observer_ptr`[(n3840)](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf)- Not yet part of the standard so C-style pointers (T*) can be used instead if needed. These work very much like a weak_ptr, but it is the programmer’s responsibility to make sure that all observers are not dereferenced after the object pointed to is disposed of.

A solution is to split the design into an object that will own all the pieces and the pieces (the cycle nodes). The owning object can use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` to automatically manage the life time of the nodes. The nodes themselves can refer to each other with `weak_ptr`, `observer_ptr`, or a Reference (Node&)