# Splitted interface of library (ChessGame with Figures etc) vs user's law to delete every pointer

Tags: c++, oop

Sometimes it's convenient to split interface of some system/library in more than one class.

For example, consider idea of library for playing Chess. Its interface would use (and deliver to players) different object for every single game and - during game - another object for every figure.

In Java there wouldn't be such a problem. But in C++, a library user can delete (or make attempt to delete) every pointer he'll get. Even `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`.

What do you think about such situations? Should I use in my interface wrapping classes that deleting isn't dangerous?

What is an usual way for such dilemmas?

Is there a way that STL smart pointers would help? I heard that they should be used always and only to express ownership, so they seem to have nothing to do with this issue (`Chess` is owner of `SingleGame`, `SingleGame` is owner of every `Figure`).

PS did I use correct tags/subject?

Comment: what?? I really didn't understand the problem.. if a programmer can't use C++ you can't save him from eternal memory damnation

Comment: Simple rule is owner deletes. So if you track ownership with a smart pointer you can track who is responsible for deleting it.

Comment: A user that deletes a pointer got via a smart pointer (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`) deserves to get leftover with debugging his crappy code himself.

Comment: So I shouldn't be worried that somebody will destroy some object too soon at all?
I'm asking about good practices. I don't want to write crappy code.

Comment: Yes, it's good practice **not** to pass around raw pointers, use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408810/smart-pointers-cycles Do you disagree with the sentence: "Approach this from the conceptual side, not the implementation one. Smart pointers represent ownership. And existence of smart pointers does not invalidate the role of raw pointers as non-owning observers." ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop a user from breaking stuff. As others have suggested, use smart pointers. With C++11, there is no reason not to use them in new code. If the user still breaks it, that's their fault. You can't design a library that is completely foolproof. You can just do your best to disuade foolish behavior.

Comment: I know, user can always write something like `int k; delete &k;`, but I talk about something that we can consider as part of public interface. 
It was on my mind lastly I wanted to know clearly how programmers look at such issues. Now I know that it is not very important.
Although, I found something that should help somebody pedantic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536280/private-operator-delete

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, smart pointers (or other RAII schemes) are often a great idea. They can clearly indicate ownership and at the same time provide an automatic mechanism for managing it. Try using such if you can.

But really, no reasonable C++ programmer should be blindly calling `delete` on every pointer they get. When they use a library/API/whatever which returns a pointer/handle/resource/etc they should be reading its documentation to tell them whether or not they will be responsible for deallocation and if so then when technique should be used.

So at a minimum, just make sure your public interface clearly indicates when ownership is passed to the caller and what method they should use for cleanup.