# How to keep multiple references between classes in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, object, pass-by-reference

I have two classes, in the example added Rectangle and Rectangles. The goal is to make one Rectangles object which holds references to multiple Rectangle objects.

If I change `r` by `r.set_values(4,4)` then off coarse `r.area()` is changed. However if I call `rectangles.rects[0].area()` it remains 12, and therefore is not changed.

As I understood I am making a reference of `r` in `rectangles`, however this seems to be wrong.

How to achieve this?

The code is available [here](http://codepad.org/hzS8zXez)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area() {return width*height;}
};

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) {
  width = x;
  height = y;
}


class Rectangles {
    public:
    Rectangles(int n);
    void addRectangle(Rectangle* r);
    Rectangle* rects;
    int nRects;
};

Rectangles::Rectangles(int n) {
    rects = new Rectangle[n];
    nRects = 0;
}

void Rectangles::addRectangle(Rectangle* r) {
    rects[nRects]   = *r;
    nRects++;
}


int main() {
    Rectangle r;
    Rectangles rectangles(5);
    r.set_values(4,3);

    rectangles.addRectangle(&r);

    cout<<"r.area() before change:"<<r.area()<<endl;
    cout<<"rectangles.rects[0].area() before change:"<<rectangles.rects[0].area()<<endl;

    r.set_values(4,4);

    cout<<"r.area() after change:"<<r.area()<<endl;
    cout<<"rectangles.rects[0].area() after change:"<<rectangles.rects[0].area()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
r.area() before change:12 
rectangles.rects[0].area() before change:12 
r.area() after change:16 
rectangles.rects[0].area() after change:12
```

Comment: No, you are not keeping a reference in `Rectangles`, you are *copying* the `Rectangle` object. If you want a collection of references, I suggest you read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg OK, how should I change this code, such that I am keeping references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with your code is your definition of `Rectangles`. It stores a pointer (or an array) to a `Rectangle`. What you want here is not an array of `Rectangle`'s, but an array of *references* to `Rectangle`'s. Here, the *references* shall be pointers, so you need to change this accordingly :

```
class Rectangles {
    public:
    Rectangles(int n);
    void addRectangle(Rectangle* r);

    // Rectangle* rects;
    // What you really want :
    Rectangle** rects;

    int nRects;
};
```

But then you also need to change the implementation :

```
Rectangles::Rectangles(int n) {
    rects = new Rectangle*[n]; // Array of pointers
    nRects = 0;
}

void Rectangles::addRectangle(Rectangle* r) {
    rects[nRects] = r; // r is a pointer : just store it, no dereferencing
    nRects++;
}
```

However, this is a bad design : you should not have to use any of these : pointer to pointer (or 'raw array' of pointers), `new`, and a class whose only purpose is to store an array of things. This is because you already have better tools for this : smart pointers (although you do not need them here either), arrays and dynamic arrays (or vectors).

So, if I were you, this is how I would rewrite your code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Rectangle {
public:
    void setSize(int w, int h);
    int area();

private:
    int width, height;
};

void Rectangle::setSize(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

int Rectangle::area() {
    return width * height;
}

int main() {
    Rectangle r;
    std::vector<Rectangle*> rectangles;
    r.setSize(4, 3);

    rectangles.push_back(&r);

    std::cout << "r.area() before change : " << r.area() << std::endl
              << "rectangles[0]->area() before change : "
              << rectangles[0]->area() << std::endl;

    r.setSize(4, 4);

    std::cout << "r.area() after change : " << r.area() << std::endl
              << "rectangles.rects[0]->area() after change : "
              << rectangles[0]->area() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit** :

You might wonder why I used a raw pointer instead of a smart pointer (since I told you to avoid pointers to pointer). This is quite simple : no smart pointer would fit the matter. Let us see why.

`std::unique_ptr` keeps sole ownership of the object. What if you want another reference to it ? Also, if you ever destroy this smart pointer via `std::vector`'s `erase`, it would also destroy your object. So if you access it afterwards, you would get some dirty error.

`std::shared_ptr` keeps shared ownership of the object. Sure, you can have another reference to your object, but the same thing happens if you destroy the pointer. Also, it has some overhead, and is not so easy to use correctly.

`std::weak_ptr` works with `std::shared_ptr`, nothing more to say.

A raw pointer, on the contrary, only needs you to ensure that the lifetime of the object is longer or equal to its own lifetime, so that you can always access your object via the pointer. And that is all.

Finally, [here is a general rule of thumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376611/3854570) (that I use) :

> - **unique_ptrs** are for sole ownership
> - **raw pointers** mean whoever gave me the raw pointer guarantees the lifetime of that object to match or exceed my lifetime.
> - **shared_ptrs** are for shared ownership
> - **weak_ptrs** are for when a system wants to check if the object still exists before using it. This is rare in my code since I find it cleaner to have a system guarantee the lifetime of anything it passes it's subsystems (in which case I use a raw pointer)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Rectangles {
public:
    void addRectangle(Rectangle* r);
    vector<Rectangle *> rects;
};

void Rectangles::addRectangle(Rectangle* r) {
    rects.push_back(r);
}

int main() {
    Rectangle r;
    Rectangles rectangles;
    r.set_values(4,3);

    rectangles.addRectangle(&r);

    cout<<"r.area() before change:"<<r.area()<<endl;
    cout<<"rectangles.rects[0]->area() before change:"<<rectangles.rects[0]->area()<<endl;

    r.set_values(4,4);

    cout<<"r.area() after change:"<<r.area()<<endl;
    cout<<"rectangles.rects[0]->area() after change:"<<rectangles.rects[0]->area()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
r.area() before change:12
rectangles.rects[0]->area() before change:12
r.area() after change:16
rectangles.rects[0]->area() after change:16
```

Comment: Looks nice, I wonder whether I can use this in an arduino program.

Comment: What is an arduino program? As long as that supports c++ it should be fine.

Comment: I just found out, that there are specific libraries for arduino and the usage of vector. So I can probably work this out.