# C++11 const correctness for raw pointer getter

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, constants

I've come across a small issue with const correctness in C++11 which I was hoping I could get clarified--I don't think it has already been asked!

Assume we have a class A, which contains an instance of class B which we want to expose. If we exposed it as a reference we would provide both const and non-const versions of the getter:

```
class B;

class A final
{
public:
    B& GetB() 
    {
        return m_b;
    }
    const B& GetB() const 
    {
        return m_b;
    }
private:
    B m_b;
};
```

However if we just had a pointer to B we would provide a getter which was const but returned a copy of the pointer to a non-const instance of B. This is because A doesn't OWN B, it only owns the the pointer, and therefore external modification of B doesn't change the state of A. (Note: I've come to this conclusion from personal experience; I've never found anything explicitly stating this is how this should work)

```
class B;

class A final
{
public:
    A(B* b) 
    {
        m_b = b;
    }
    A* GetB() const
    {
        return m_b;
    }
private:
    B* m_b;
};
```

This all makes sense so far, but what do we do if A owns a unique pointer (or shared pointer for that matter) to B? A now logically owns B--even if not literally. Up until now I've been following the second example above when exposing a raw pointer to a shared pointer, but since A logically owns B should I be doing something more similar to the first example?

```
class B;

class A final
{
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<B> b)
    {
        m_b = std::move(b);
    }
    B* GetB()
    {
        return m_b.get();
    }
    const B* GetB() const
    {
        return m_b.get();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};
```

Comment: It is up to you to choose the restriction of the return type you want when using pointer/smart_pointer.

Comment: No, you would not provide both versions of the getter. Only a `const`-qualified getter and a not `const`-qualified setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ownership situation it would IMHO be unnatural if a member function could allow modification of a part of a logically `const` object, but that's a design issue.

However, do note that a raw pointer *can* be used to implement ownership.

For example, consider an internal array implemented with direct `new`-ing and raw pointer. You would not want an interface that would break when/if that was replaced with a `std::vector` for handling the storage. And so the rule for whether to provide a `const`/non-`const` pair of accessor functions must be rooted in the design level, not in what the language *permits* for a given implementation of the design.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, if your design was correct when `A` held a `B` by value, then I'd use the same const/non-const accessors for the case when `A` holds a `B` by `std::unique_ptr`.

Why? Barring some additional means of ownership transfer away from `A` (such as a move assignment operator), in both cases `A` owns a `B` that will live and die with it. That in the latter case the `B` instance happened to have been allocated separately on the heap and provided to the constructor is immaterial; its lifetime is the same.

There's yet another variation of your example that may help settle your vacillation, assuming that we don't need to deal with the possibility of `A::m_b` being null:

```
class B
{
  // ...
};

class A final
{
public:
  A() : m_b(std::make_unique<B>())
  {}

  B& GetB()
  {
    return *m_b;
  }

  const B& GetB() const
  {
    return *m_b;
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};
```

Here, `A` clearly owns its `B`, and offers no way to transfer ownership. I don't know *why* we'd allocate `B` on the heap here, but we can just to make a point. (Note that now `A::GetB()` returns by reference rather than pointer.) With this example, would you still have a hard time deciding how to write `A::GetB()` and whether to overload it on const?

Comment: What would happen in your example if m_b happens to be `nullptr`?

Comment: Are you suggesting that `std::make_unique<B>()` could return null? Or are you considering the case where `A`'s constructor accepts a `std::unique_ptr<B>` parameter? Regardless, if `m_b` winds up as null in the latter case, then calling either `A::GetB()` overload would crash, likely triggering a segmentation fault. I have no idea whether an `A`—or its callers—is supposed to work in concert with a null `B` pointer.

Comment: I'm considering the case where `A`'s constructor would accept a `std::unique_ptr<B>` as a parameter in initialization (be it in ctor or via setters). With a raw ptr the client is able to perform a null check on the return value of `GetB`. It is not possible with a reference. I would add to your example a `bool hasB()` method to `A` that checks if `m_b` is `nullptr`.

Comment: @seh This is definitely a good point for places where it can safely be implemented. However the in the scenarios that prompted me to ask the question I would definitely have to be dealing with nullptr, which, as dureuill pointed out, would mean returning by reference would be a bad idea. I tried to make that clear by passing the unique_ptr in the constructor, but I probably should have explicitly stated it :)

Comment: Yes, if you want to accommodate `A::m_b` being null, then you need what the book *Elements of Programming* calls a *definition-space predicate*: a function to indicate whether or not `m_b` is populated with a valid instance. Alternately, by returning pointers, you allow your caller to check whether the pointers are null, using the predicate built in to the language itself.

Answer (score 2):

While I do not have much authority to answer design questions, I would use something akin to has been proposed in @seh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26528949/1614219), with the addition of a way to check for the null value of `m_b`:

```
class B
{
  // ...
};

class A final
{
public:
  A(std::ptr<B> b) : m_b(std::move(b))
  {}

  bool HasB()
  {
    return m_b != nullptr;
  }

  B& GetB()
  {
    return *m_b;
  }

  const B& GetB() const
  {
    return *m_b;
  }

 private:
   std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};
```

If you really can't do without pointers (legacy API), then it is more of a grey line. I would declare both `const B* GetB() const` and `B* GetB()`, since a common convention in C++11 is that [raw pointers can be used to represent non-owning pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376611/1614219). Ultimately this would have to been indicated in documentation, though.