# What are the pros and cons of using smart pointers as "non-owning references"?

Tags: c++, memory-safety

When an object needs to refer to another object without "owning it" (i.e., not responsible for its lifetime), one way is simply to use raw pointers or raw references for this, like in this example:

```
class Node
{
    std::vector<Edge*> incidentEdges;
};

class Edge
{
    Node* startNode;
    Node* endNode;
};

class Graph
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node*>> nodes;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Edge*>> edges;
};
```

<sup>(please save yourself the time to comment on the existence of more efficient data structures for graphs, that's my field of expertise and not the point of the question.)</sup>

`Graph` is responsible for the lifetime of nodes and edges, and responsible to guarantee that the pointers in `Node` and `Edge` are not dangling. But if the programmer fails to do so, then there is a risk of undefined behavior.

But with the overhead cost of reference counting, one could strongly enforce that no undefined behaviour can occur using smart pointers. Instead it would gracefully crash. It guarantees that this happens at the earliest possible time (avoid corrupting more data) and don't go unnoticed. Here is one possible implementation:

<sup>(edit: fixed implementation, more details in [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949702/1951907) answer. Huge thanks!)</sup>

```
template <class T>
using owning_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;

template <class T>
class nonowning_ptr
{
    std::weak_ptr p_;

public:
    nonowning_ptr() : p_() {}
    nonowning_ptr(const nonowning_ptr & p) : p_(p.p_) {}
    nonowning_ptr(const owning_ptr<T> & p) : p_(p) {}

    // checked dereferencing
    owning_ptr<T> get() const
    { 
        if (auto sp = p_.lock())
        {
            return sp.get();
        }
        else
        {
            logUsefulInfo();
            saveRecoverableUserData();
            nicelyInformUserAboutError();
            abort(); // or throw exception
        }
    }

    T & operator*() const = delete; // cannot be made safe
    owning_ptr<T> operator->() const { return get(); }

    // [...] other methods forwarding weak_ptr functionality 
};

class Node
{
    std::vector<nonowning_ptr<Edge>> incidentEdges;
};

class Edge
{
    nonowning_ptr<Node> startNode;
    nonowning_ptr<Node> endNode;
};

class Graph
{
    std::vector<owning_ptr<Node>>> nodes;
    std::vector<owning_ptr<Edge>>> edges;
};
```

My question is: apart from the obvious performance vs. safety trade-off, what are the pros and cons of each approach?

I'm not asking which one is the best, there surely is no best and it depends on use cases. I'm asking for factual pros and cons of each method that you may be aware of and that I'm not, which would help take design decisions (maybe, in term of readability? maintainability? portability? playing nice with third-party library? [preventing use-after-free exploits?](http://wenke.gtisc.gatech.edu/papers/dangnull.pdf)).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having a non owning raw pointer.

Comment: Well, that's an opinion. I know world-class engineers that would disagree with this. State-of-the-art research as well, such as this paper from 2015: http://wenke.gtisc.gatech.edu/papers/dangnull.pdf

Comment: @NathanOliver So the fact is: there *are* wrong things with non-owning raw pointer. The question is: what are the trade-offs that comes with not using them? Is it worth the trouble?

Comment: Well [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8376611/4342498) is my guideline.  IMHO it is question of do you allow the user to shoot themselves in the foot or do you baby them and consume more resources.  As long as you state the pointer passed to your class must outlive your class then the onus is on the user.

Comment: It should also be noted that the core C++ guidelines also say that non-owning pointers should be raw pointers. Or rather, if you have a raw pointer, you don't own it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thx, that link is useful, I missed it before!

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I had actually read that already. I think I agree as a guideline :-) But I'd still appreciate a factual list of various pros and cons. One might say that if performance is not critical, then we could use another language than C++. But sometimes only a few parts are critical and is more convenient to keep the whole system written in one language.

Comment: Note that there is a light-weight observing pointer proposal floating around.  It does not wrap a `weak_ptr`, but rather is intended to document that this pointer does not represent ownership in code bases where `T*` is sometimes owning, sometimes not.

Comment: I get where you are coming from with this. If I were to have such a pointer at my disposal I would want it to be a *drop in* replacement for a *raw pointer* to the code that builds the *network* so that I could use the *smart pointer* in `DEBUG` code and *raw pointers* in production code. After all once you have proved the network building code is sound, why constantly keep checking it at run-time?

Comment: @Galik Yes, that would definitely be a very sensible approach! Or keep the check in all beta versions even when compiling in release mode. Or don't be foolish enough to think that all memory issues where fixed before release, and still keep the checks for stable releases. Maybe remove them after 5 years of usage by millions of users without crashes. One advantage is definitely the flexibility: checking can be toggled on and off easily, it's just up to the developer to draw the line of when it's worth checking and when it's not.

Comment: I do not really see any point in this special `nonowning_ptr` class. If you want the sematics of checking for pointer validity, just use weak_ptr - this is what it is for. Your class doesn't really help anybody, and hides the nature of the pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA Two reasons: 1) readability. The whole point is to write safe code, and readability makes this more likely. 2) As pointed out by Galik, it allows to switch from checked pointers to raw pointers without changing any code.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is: apart from the obvious performance vs. safety trade-off, what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Ignoring the fact that there are no other questions for smart pointers *besides* performance and safety (performance is *why* we don't just let a GC handle it safely), there's the fact that your `nonowning_ptr` class is *horribly broken.*

Your `get` function returns a naked pointer. Yet there is no guarantee anywhere in your code that any user of `get` will get either a valid pointer or `NULL`.

The very instant you destroy the `shared_ptr` returned by `weak_ptr::lock`, you remove the only thing that keeps that memory valid. Which means that, if someone comes along and deletes the last `shared_ptr` to that memory while your have your `T*`, you're screwed.

Threading in particular breaks your illusions of safety.

So the most important "con" of `nonowning_ptr` is that it's broken; it's no safer than a `T*`.

Comment: Thx! Do you know is there is any non-broken alternative? Or if (apart from a macro), it's possible to replace `if(auto sp = lock() ) { sp->doSomething(); } else { abort(); }` by `sp->doSomething();`, for syntactic sugar? (I'm not even sure that's possible with a macro)

Comment: @Boris: That's a completely different question. But don't bother to ask, because outside of macro magic, the answer is "no". And even with macro magic, I'd guess that it's unlikely.

Comment: @NicolBolas The answer is "yes", because `a->b` is **magic**.  See my answer.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk: He didn't ask about returning a `shared_ptr`. He asked about a way to make `sp->doSomething` become a mini-function call with a call to `abort` if the pointer wasn't present. While your suggestion would achieve a similar effect, it's still not exactly what he asked for.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, my question in the comment above was more loosely defined. By "replace", I really meant something that achieves equivalent functionality, which Yakk does provide. :-)

Comment: @NicolBolas In what way does my solution not call `abort` if the pointer wasn't present, and `sp->doSomething()` if it is present, which is the point of Boris's problem?

Answer (score 4):

Your design has a problem, in that if another thread or path of execution (say, multiple arguments to a function call) modifies the `shared_ptr` underlying your `weak_ptr`, the check for lifetime will be made, and before you use it you get UB.

To reduce this, `T * get()` should be `std::shared_ptr<T> get()`.  And `operator->` should also return `std::shared_ptr<T>`.  While this seems impractical, it actually works due to the fun way `->` is defined in C++ to auto-recurse.  (`a->` is defined as `(*a).` if `a` is a pointer type, and `(a.operator->())->` otherwise.  So your `->` returns a `shared_ptr`, which then has `->` called on it, which then returns the pointer.  This ensures the lifetime of the pointer you are doing `->` on is long enough.)

```
// checked dereferencing
std::shared_ptr<T> get() const
{ 
  if (auto sp = lock())
    return sp;
  fail();
}

void fail() { abort() } // or whatever
T & operator*() const = delete; // cannot be made safe
std::shared_ptr<T> operator->() const { return get(); } // works, magically

operator std::shared_ptr<T>() const { return lock(); }
std::shared_ptr<T> lock() const { return p_.lock(); }
```

now `p->foo();` is (in effect) `p->get()->foo()`.  The lifetime of the `get()` `shared_ptr` return value is longer than the call to `foo()`, so everything is safe as houses.

There is still a hole in the `T& operator()` call, where the reference could outlive its owned object, but this at least patches the `->` hole.

You could choose to ban the `T& operator*()` entirely for safety.

A `shared_reference<T>` could be written to patch that last hole, but `operator.` isn't available yet.

Similarly, a `operator shared_ptr<T>()` would be nice, and a `.lock()` method, to allow temporary multi-line ownership.  Maybe even `explicit operator bool()` but that runs into the "check, then do, but the check might be invalid before the do" problem that shared pointers and file operations have.

Comment: awesome, thx! Well, that doesn't answer the actual question, but is super useful. I can totally ban `get()` and `T& operator()`. I also have implement edin my actual tests and `explicit operator bool()` for those non-owning cases where the pointer may indeed be valid or not, but I realized in those cases I'd rather do a lock explicitely, since it doesn't affect readability much.