# Abstract types Meet std Containers

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I've been trying to solve a design problem involving both an abstract type and its derived classes, as well as std containers. I have a working solution, but I would like to see if it can be improved. I apologize for the "..."s. But it is to make the design issue more clear.

```
// the base class
class B { 
private:
    ...
public:
    // the virtual function which makes B an abstract type
    virtual void func(...) = 0; 
    ...
};

// the 1st derived class
class D1 : public B { 
    ...
    void func(...) {...}
};

// the 2nd derived class
class D2 : public B {
    ...
    void func(...) {...}
};
```

Based on the problem, both `D1` and `D2` have to *point to* or *contain* some instances of `B` w/o knowing their concrete types. Currently, I'm using the *point to* approach, which means `D1` and `D2` contain some pointers to `B`.

In addition, those pointed-to instances of `B` are in fact *shared* among higher-level instances of `B` in recursive compositions. To make it clear, I'll expand the definition of `D1`.

```
class D1 : public B { 
private:
    B *d1_b1;
    B *d1_b2;
    ...
public:
    D1 (B *b1, B *b2) {...}
    B* func(...) {...}
    ...
};
```

Now, although `d1_b1` and `d1_b2` are shared by some higher-level instances of either `D1` or `D2`, I think **none of higher-level objects should maintain the ownership or lifetime of lower-level objects**. Instead, I use an std container with `unique_ptr`s, for example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> unique_b_objs;
```

The `unique_b_objs` is declared at the scope where the recursive construction is first called, and is passed in by reference and used recursively.

Now, every time an new object of either `D1` or `D2` is created, a corresponding `unique_ptr` is pushed back into `unique_b_objs`. Essentially, the **raw pointers to objects of B** are used in recursive composition, but **the lifetime and ownership of the objects of B are managed by the std container**.

I hope I've made it clear so far. It's working as expected. But I'm trying to **get rid of the raw pointers**. I can think of two approaches, but none of them work right now.

- **Use the "contain" approach**. Essentially, all the `B *` becomes `B` in `D1` and `D2`. But `B` is an abstract type, which means compilers won't even compile something like `D1 (B b1, B b2) {...}`
- **Use reference in the container**. It can be done via the `reference_wrapper`. However, since the objects are created locally in recursions, the references become invalid out of the scope. This means we cannot transport references between recursive calls.

One working approach is to use `shared_ptr`. But it is unnecessary to share the ownership at every recursion step. And it also leads to performance overhead.

At this point, thank you for reading through the question. I hope I've made it clear. If you can think of some better approach than a container of `unique_ptr`s + raw pointers, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you want to "get rid of the raw pointers"? It is perfectly fine to use non-owning raw pointer (for example, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8376611/4899740)).

Comment: @Serikov, by "I'm trying to get rid of the raw pointers", it actually means "My coworker insists on getting rid of the raw pointers"... :(

Comment: Maybe your coworker uncomfortable with separation of object lifetimes from objects? If you need to pass resulting structure somewhere you need to make shure that objects is not expired. If it is the case you can wrap this structure in object (for example, `Graph`) that will control lifetime of it's nodes. Either way, when lifetime of created object is controled from outside (either by `vector` or some other means) you could use reference instead of pointers in your constructors.

Comment: @Serikov. Assume that the objects are controlled by a vector, and we use reference instead of pointers, can you elaborate a bit more? In this particular case, my understanding is that the objects of `B` cannot be **contained** in the vector, due to `B` being an abstract type. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: If you store `unique_ptr`s in your `vector` as you do now, when another object is pushed in vector, pointers (or references) to `unique_ptr`s will be invalidated but pointers (and references) to objects stored through unique_ptr will not. So you can use reference to them. Instead of using D1(unique1.get(), unique2.get()) you can use D1(*unique, *unique) (and change that constructor to get references).

Comment: @Serikov. unique1's type is `unique_ptr<B>`, right? If so, `unique1.get()` should return `B *`. Maybe I missed where hte reference is used? `D1(*unique, *unique)`...I'm not sure what is the type of `unique`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use non-owning raw pointer (for example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376611/4899740)).
If your goal is to use references instead of pointers in constructors and members of your derived classes, you can do this without significant changes to your design.
For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class B {
private:
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> arena;

class D1 : public B {
    B &b1;
    B &b2;
public:
    D1(B &b1, B &b2) : b1(b1), b2(b2) { }
    void func() {
        std::cout << "D1\n";
        b1.func();
        b2.func();
    }
};

class D2 : public B {
    B &b;
public:
    D2(B &b) : b(b) { }
    void func() {
        std::cout << "D2\n";
        b.func();
    }
};

class D3 : public B {
public:
    D3() { }
    void func() {
        std::cout << "D3\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    auto node = std::make_unique<D3>(); // make new object
    auto& nodeRef = *node; // get reference to the object
    arena.push_back(std::move(node)); // transfer ownership to the vector,
                                      // nodeRef is not invalidated

    auto node1 = std::make_unique<D2>(nodeRef); // use reference
    auto& node1Ref = *node1;
    arena.push_back(std::move(node1));

    auto node2 = std::make_unique<D3>();
    auto& node2Ref = *node2;
    arena.push_back(std::move(node2));

    auto node3 = std::make_unique<D1>(node1Ref, node2Ref);
    arena.push_back(std::move(node2));
    node3->func();
}
```